# Coffeescript cannot find div - railscast 114 revised

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3.1, coffeescript, railscasts

Trying to follow the guide of railscast 114 with the endless page using `will_paginate` but I get an error from my coffeescript:

## home.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
if $('.pagination').length
  $(window).scroll ->
   url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
   if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
     $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...")
     $.getScript(url)
$(window).scroll()
```

On the line:

```
   if $('.pagination').length
```

I get the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

It seems like the script does not read my index file because the script can't find any of my div-boxes...

Please help... been stuck with this problem of the endless page for a week now.

## Update coffeescript

```
jQuery ->
  if $('.pagination').length
    $(window).scroll ->
      url = $('.pagination .next_page').attr('href')
      if url && $(window).scrollTop() > $(document).height() - $(window).height() - 50
        $('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...")
        $.getScript(url)
    $(window).scroll()
```

Comment: Please note that the 'updated' version is functionally different. It will compile to different JavaScript code. I think you may fight two problems simultaneously here.

Answer (score 1):

In order for this to work, you need to execute selectors after the DOM is loaded. You correctly defined a function in the first line to achieve that, but this function (that is executed on `document.ready`) has an empty body.

In simple words, indent all the code except for the first line by one level.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

It does not seem like it is working... I really just copy-pasted the coffeescript code from the railscast but it did no quites seem to work.

Comment: And if I try:
$(document).ready -> alert 'blah'
Before the if-statement I get the following error:
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<HTMLDocument> has no method 'ready' 

If that helps...

Answer (score 0):

This was solved by moving the coffeescript into application.js, rewriting it in jQuery and then calling var $j = jQuery.noConflict(); and appending the $j sign in front of evert $-sign. Don't know why this worked. Think it has to do with multiple scripts running at the same time.

It now looks like this:

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function() {
if ($j('.pagination').length) {
$j(window).scroll(function() {
var url;
url = $j('.pagination .next_page').attr('href');
if (url && $j(window).scrollTop() > $j(document).height() - $j(window).height() - 50) {
$j('.pagination').text("Fetching more products...");
return $j.getScript(url);
}
});
return $j(window).scroll();
}
})
```

Comment: What other libraries do use use? MooTools? Zepto? Prototype? It's quite unusual to have conflicts with jQuery.

Comment: I was using Prototype. I am pretty sure I disabled it though. Took me forever to figure out how to go around the conflicts...

*Note to anyone who had the same problem. You have to do the same thing in your index.js.erb